# IndexError: list index out of range discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

ok so I tried making a lvl system and it worked so far, but now I want to make a command where it shows lvl and xp in embed.

but im getting an error`IndexError: list index out of range`

i defined my xp and lvl like that

```py
async def lvl_up(self, user):
    cur_xp = user['xp']
    cur_lvl = user['lvl']
```

and wanted to send it in embed like this

```py
embed=discord.Embed()
embed.add_field(name="Level", value=user[0]['lvl'], inline=True)
embed.add_field(name="XP", value=user[0]['xp'], inline=True)
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

but those values don't work like that i think...

Comment: Show the full error log.

Comment: @mikss show us more if your code, you haven't shown anything. How are you invoking the function, where did you declare `value`, etc. Or if it's not to big, post everything.

Answer (score 0):

Usually an Index out of range error just means that the the index you are asking for doesnt exist. So that means that:
`value=user[0]['lvl']` could be the problem since it couldnt find the index 0 of user.